# wpf numeric a control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a grid filled with buttons. Is there any way to give each button some kind of numeric value? (some kind of a tag that I could later refer to when comparing the buttons).

I tried using the Tag property but it seems not to accept numbers (unless precedent by letters).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A string seems to fit the bill, why do you want a number type?

Comment: can you explain more about your view, it sounds as if there is a better way to achieve than what you are trying..

Comment: sounds like and [X Y poblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: *I tried using the Tag property but it seems not to accept numbers*... that's strange, because the `Tag` property is an `object` and so excepts anything as its value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding this to a view model, to do something on the click of a button, then you could do it like this:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Content="1" Command="{Binding NumberButton}" CommandParameter="1"/>
<Button Name="Button2" Content="2" Command="{Binding NumberButton}" CommandParameter="2"/>    
....
```

Then in the command you've bound to in your viewmodel, you can do something appropriate with the command parameter which has been passed in:

```
NumberButton = new DelegateCommand<string>(number =>
{
    /*... */
}, i => true);
```